# Как получить текст ссылки с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно из ссылки, достать содержимое, а именно число 719

```
<a href="http://anysite.ru/?product_tag=719" rel="tag">719</a>
```

Comment: Тут два раза встречается число 719.

Comment: `";<a href="http://anysite\.ru/\?product_tag=(\d+)" rel="tag">(\d+)</a>;i"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я вижу здесь несколько способов решения
Первый - использовать XML

```
$xmlstr='<a href="http://anysite.ru/?product_tag=719" rel="tag">719</a>';  

$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $movies->a;
```

Второй способ по регулярке

```
preg_match_all('/product_tag=([0-9]+)/', $xmlstr, $result);
print_r($result);
```